# Finding corresponding day to lecture by webscraping

Tags: html, python-3.x, datetime, beautifulsoup

So I have this website which consists of several tables, they look like the one below.

[image]

The tables simply shows when I have my next lecture and the URL to the table can be found in the code below

Now, I want to scrape this website and obtain the following information

```
Date, Time, Course name, Lecturer
```

The code below, almost does this. It finds every lecture, the name and the relevant information. *However*, I was not able to figure out which day a particular lecture occurs. How can I match the lecture that i scraped, to the corresponding date?

Output

```
['08:15-10:00', 'Forelesning i Matematikk og Fysikk', 'I.F. Pedersen']
['08:15-10:00', 'Forelesning i Matematikk og Fysikk', 'Ø. Søvik']
['10:15-12:00', 'Forelesning i Matematikk og Fysikk', 'Ø. Søvik']
['12:15-14:00', 'Forelesning i Matematikk og Fysikk', 'Ø. Søvik']
```

Desired output

```
['22.09.2020', '08:15-10:00', 'Forelesning i Matematikk og Fysikk', 'I.F. Pedersen']
['24.09.2020', '08:15-10:00', 'Forelesning i Matematikk og Fysikk', 'Ø. Søvik']
['21.09.2020', '10:15-12:00', 'Forelesning i Matematikk og Fysikk', 'Ø. Søvik']
['23.09.2020', '12:15-14:00', 'Forelesning i Matematikk og Fysikk', 'Ø. Søvik']
```

Here is what I have attempted so far

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
 
today = datetime.date.today()
year, week_num, day_of_week = today.isocalendar()  # DOW = day of week
 
URL = "http://timeplan.uit.no/emne_timeplan.php?sem=20h&module[]=TEK-0002-1#week-38"
page = requests.get(URL)
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
 
results = soup.find(id="week-{}".format(week_num), class_="div_week")
 
# print(results.prettify())
 
lectures = []
 
for name in results.find_all("td", class_="object-cell"):
    title = name.find("span", class_="act-desc").get_text()
    if "forelesning" in title.lower():
        time = name.find("td", class_="object-cell-1-0").get_text()
        lecturer = name.find("a", class_="staff_url").get_text()
        lectures.append([time, title, lecturer])
 
rows = results.find("table").find("tbody").find_all("tr")
 
for lecture in lectures:
    print(lecture)
```

Comment: You should share the HTML of this page or section, it could help to find an algorithm that could fit

Comment: I think it would be easier just inspect it using `CTRL+I` on the actual page? The HTML as most modern websites, it is just an endless mess of table row and column elements so I do not think much would be gained by just pasting the code.

Comment: Is your data inside a table formed like: 
`<table><tr><th>...</th></tr> <tr><td>...</td></tr></table>` or is it done in an other manner ?

Comment: Yes. I scrape for `<div id="week-39"> .. </div>` and whitin this is a table, eg `<table><tr><th>...</th></tr> <tr><td>...</td></tr></table>` However, when I tried to extract the rows I obtained a mess of 27 rows or something which did not give me anything to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `name` variable you use in your loop you will see some tags related to a detail popover on the page. In this popover you will have the date you're interested in:

```
for name in results.find_all("td", class_="object-cell"):
    title = name.find("span", class_="act-desc").get_text()
    #Find a `a` tag that has a data-content attribute
    popover = BeautifulSoup(name.find('a', {'data-content':True}).get('data-content'))
    #Process this attribute as html and grab the date
    date = popover.find('td',text='Dato').find_next('td').text

    #... your script proceeds
    if "forelesning" in title.lower():
        time = name.find("td", class_="object-cell-1-0").get_text()
        lecturer = name.find("a", class_="staff_url").get_text()
        lectures.append([date, time, title, lecturer])
```

Ouput:

```
['22.09.2020 (Uke 39)', '08:15-10:00', 'Forelesning Matematikk og fysikk', 'I.F. Pedersen']
['24.09.2020 (Uke 39)', '08:15-10:00', 'Forelesning Matematikk og fysikk', 'Ø. Søvik']
['21.09.2020 (Uke 39)', '10:15-12:00', 'Forelesning Matematikk og fysikk', 'Ø. Søvik']
['23.09.2020 (Uke 39)', '12:15-14:00', 'Forelesning Matematikk og fysikk', 'Ø. Søvik']
```

Comment: I never considered scraping the pop up! Thanks this works perfectly, any reason why you can not use `name.find` directly but have to wrap it i a `BeautifulSoup`? Anyways, it works great.

Comment: you'll see that the popover code is nested in an attribute, not direxctly in the global html. This is why I extracted the attribute and then processed it as html